# Angular.js - ui router | How to make sure the value of $stateParams.anyParam is integer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Below is the code of part of config of $stateProvider. I want to check the appId paramter to be integer before it gets passed to my controller. How can I do that here if possible? 
Currently user types the whole url and provides any string for appId where integer is expected then I am getting errrors. For example "/app/dfsad" instead of "/app/12". I have placed checks it in the controller but i want to check it before it gets passed to the controller. Thanks. 
For example, I want appId to be converted to 0 (by default) if value is not a valid number. Thanks!

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app/:appId',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/project/project.html',
    controller: 'projectController',
    resolve: {
        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                {
                    name: 'projectModule',
                    serie: true,
                    files: [
                            'app/components/project/projectCharts.js', 
                            'app/components/project/utils/projectUtils.js', 
                            'app/components/project/projectModule.js'
                           ]

                }

            ]);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ui-router supports this behaviour : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

You can specify a type in url :

```
url: '/app/{appId:int}'
```

Otherwise, you could have a look at [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), at the onEnter callback, in which you could alter the parameter, which may help you (but I'd replace the `{appId:int}` by `:appId`, to allow entering the state. Not sure if it is really before the controller is created.

Comment: Thanks @mathieu I have added this fix. It takes me to default route if appId is not int, which i dont want. i want it to convert non-int values to 0.